# Sending SMS in windows phone over wi-fi or data

Tags: windows-phone-8, sms

I want to include SMS in my windows phone app.

I know that there exists **SMS Compose Task launcher** for the same, but is there some way we can send SMS via a wi-fi or over data, cause I assume that  SMS Compose Task would incur sim charges and people today mostly prefer data messages.

Is there any whatsapp API available or be integrated into the app?.

Answer (score 2):

If you are sending an actual sms then somebody is going to incur a charge somewhere, wether that be the user or the developer.

You could use a service such as [Twilio](http://www.twilio.com/sms/api) which can send actual SMS messages or you could use something like [SignalR](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR) which allows for real time messaging to build you own messaging backend.

Hope this helps.

Comment: +1. An SMS will always carry some sort of charge, no getting around that.  Need to find a third party company who you can send some data to their service and they send the SMS for you.

Comment: So we cannot send SMS using wi-fi or over data, thereby not charging the person, but using his mobile data plan itself.

Comment: Not SMS, but you can send messages like WhatsApp does using something like SignalR above...